# Python, Grabbing information from a class object not working

Tags: python, list, class, object, append

So I have no idea what's causing this error. I don't know how to describe it without showing you, so here's the relevant part of my code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, contents, children):
        self.contents = contents
        self.children = children


def makeNode(district, parent):
    new_contents = parent.contents
    new_contents.append(district)
    new = Node(new_contents, [])
    parent.children.append(new)
    return new


root = Node([], [])
data = [[1,1,'r'],[1,2,'d'],[1,2,'r'],[1,4,'d']]
makeNode(data, root)
```

Here's the problem: new.contents is changed as planned, but so is parent.contents. What happened?

Comment: Hint: what is the output of the script `a = []; b = a.append(23); print(b)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending item to lists - python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505529/appending-item-to-lists-python)

Comment: As an aside, you create class level `contents` and `children` and then create object level versions of the same variables in `__init__`. Do you use the class level lists anywhere? If not, you should just remove them.

Comment: Updated question for problem that still arises: now parent and new are changed.

Comment: Fixed, needed to copy the list before referencing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned it in your comment, you've got to copy the *contents* pf 'parent.contents' into 'new_contents'. Otherwise, you're accessing the list by reference, which is obviously not what is intended.

So, your 'makeNode' function could start as follows:

```
def makeNode(district, parent):
    new_content = copy.deepcopy(parent.contents)
    ...
```

I hope, I could clear things up for later readers... ;)

Comment: Actually, new_content = list(parent.contents) even worked. But thanks!