# Reading inputs written in different lines from a file and storing each input inside a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to read a file named `one.txt` which contains the following:

```
hat
cow
Zu6
This is a sentence
```

and I'm trying to store each string written on each line inside a list. For example, my output list should contain the following elements:

```
['hat', 'cow', 'Zu6', 'This is a sentence']
```

Here's my approach for doing this:

```
def first(ss):
    f = open(ss, 'r')
    text = f.readline()
    f.close()
    lines = []
    li = [lines.append(line) for line in text]
    print li

first('D:\\abc\\1\\one.txt')
```

However, when I try to print `li`, here's what I get as the output:

```
[None, None, None, None]
```

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Appending item to lists within a list comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505529/appending-item-to-lists-within-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print list(open("my_text.txt"))
```

is probably a pretty easy way to do it ...

ofc people are gonna come screaming about dangling pointers so for the sake of good habits

```
with open("my_text.txt") as f:
     print list(f)
```

alternatively

```
f.readlines()
```

you might need to strip off some newline characters

```
[line.strip() for line in f]
```

Comment: I tried using the readlines() method, but still got the same output. Your previous solutions work for me. I'd still like to know what was going wrong in my approach though.

Comment: `a_list.append(value)` alters a list in place and returns `None`  ... try printing `lines` instead