# Generating a list from another list using List comprehension in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through a list and generate another list. is this achievable using list comprehension?

```
source = ['1/2','1/3','1/4']
port_hdl_dict  = {'1/2':'1/1/2','1/3':'1/1/3','1/4':'1/1/4','1/5':'1/1/5'}

def getSourcePortlistIxia(source_list,port_hdl_dict):
    source_port_list = []
    for i in source_list:
        source_port_list.append(port_hdl_dict[i])

    return(source_port_list)


res = getSourcePortlistIxia(source,port_hdl_dict)
print(res)
```

This i tried to acheive this using liist comprehension

```
source_port_list = []
my_list = [source_port_list.append(port_hdl_dict[i]) for i in source]
print(my_list)
```

but this prints the output as

```
['1/1/2', '1/1/3', '1/1/4']
[None, None, None]
```

am I doing anything wrong here? how do we achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending item to lists within a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505529/appending-item-to-lists-within-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating a list, or another iterable structure from a list is one of the best use cases for list comprehension. The problem with your code is that the `append` operation doesn't return anything. Because that's what you're storing inside `my_list`, when you print `my_list`, you get `[None, None, None]`

Furthermore, it seems to me that what you're actually trying to do is get all values from a dictionary, for a given set of keys.

You can achieve that by, instead of using a third list that you append to, returning the value in the dictionary, inside the list comprehension, as such:

```py
my_list = [port_hdl_dict[i] for i in source]
```

The above is a very naive example with no validation. So, for example, if `i` was not a valid key inside `port_hdl_dict`, then your code would raise an exception.
You can add some simple validation by simply checking `i` is in `port_hdl_dict`

```py
my_list = [port_hdl_dict[i] for i in source if i in port_hdl_dict]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [port_hdl_dict.get(v) for v in source]
```