# Inserting value to every nth element in list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists in the following manner:

```py
[[45.0, 58.0, 45.0, 520.0],
 [45.0, 58.0, 754.0, 58.0],
 [302.0, 58.0, 302.0, 520.0],
 [563.0, 58.0, 563.0, 520.0],
 [626.0, 58.0, 626.0, 257.0],
 [754.0, 58.0, 754.0, 321.0],
 [563.0, 159.0, 754.0, 159.0],
 [626.0, 257.0, 754.0, 257.0],
 [45.0, 260.0, 110.0, 260.0],
 [302.0, 260.0, 563.0, 260.0],
 [629.0, 321.0, 629.0, 520.0],
 [45.0, 520.0, 629.0, 520.0],
 [110.0, 58.0, 110.0, 322.0],
 [45.0, 129.0, 110.0, 129.0],
 [45.0, 322.0, 302.0, 322.0],
 [563.0, 321.0, 754.0, 321.0],
 [299.0, 520.0, 299.0, 581.0],
 [299.0, 581.0, 562.0, 581.0],
 [562.0, 520.0, 562.0, 581.0],
 [563.0, 450.0, 629.0, 450.0]]
```

Is there a way I could add for example the element `2` to every second index inside the lists?

So the result would look like:

```py
[[45.0, 58.0, 2, 45.0, 520.0, 2],
 [45.0, 58.0, 2, 754.0, 58.0, 2],
 [302.0, 58.0, 2, 302.0, 520.0, 2],
 [563.0, 58.0, 2, 563.0, 520.0, 2],
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are the lists always of length 4?

Comment: Indeed they are!

Comment: use `insert()` method

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution for your issue, using python list properties

```py
def insert_in_position(_list, element, position):
    for i in range(len(_list)):
        _list[i] = _list[i][:position]+[element]+_list[i][position:]
    return _list
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `insert()`, `append()`, and [List Comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension).

```
your_list = [[45.0, 58.0, 45.0, 520.0],
    [45.0, 58.0, 754.0, 58.0],
    ...
    [562.0, 520.0, 562.0, 581.0],
    [563.0, 450.0, 629.0, 450.0]]

new_list = [x.insert(2, 2) or x.append(2) or x for x in your_list]

print(new_list)

# result:
[[45.0, 58.0, 2, 45.0, 520.0, 2],
[45.0, 58.0, 2, 754.0, 58.0, 2],
...
[562.0, 520.0, 2, 562.0, 581.0, 2],
[563.0, 450.0, 2, 629.0, 450.0, 2]]
```

You may also check this **Helpful Link**: [Appending item to lists within a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505529/appending-item-to-lists-within-a-list-comprehension).

Comment: This is an abuse of list comprehensions, and using `or` misleadingly suggests there is some possibility of branching when there isn't. If you want to modify the contents of the list in place with `insert` or `append` then use a regular `for` loop; it is very strange (and can lead to subtle bugs) to update the outer list out-of-place but the inner lists in-place.

Comment: From your "helpful link": *List comprehensions are for storing the result, which isn't what you want in this case if you want to just change the original lists.*

Answer (score 0):

More pythonic way:

```
data = [[45.0, 58.0, 45.0, 520.0],
    [45.0, 58.0, 754.0, 58.0],
    ...
    [562.0, 520.0, 562.0, 581.0],
    [563.0, 450.0, 629.0, 450.0]]

#Directly appending an element to item will impact original dataset, 
#Since list is reference data structure,

for item in data:
    item.append(2) 
print(data)

[[45.0, 58.0, 2, 45.0, 520.0, 2],
[45.0, 58.0, 2, 754.0, 58.0, 2],
...
[562.0, 520.0, 2, 562.0, 581.0, 2],
[563.0, 450.0, 2, 629.0, 450.0, 2]]
```